# URL rewriting for cakephp on local OSX apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have set up apache on OSX for local web dev use and made a dynamic vhost using dnsmasq such that visiting `foo.dev` will point to the `/foo` directory in my `~/Sites/sites` folder.

This is what the vhost rule looks like:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/harryg/Sites/sites/%1"
<Directory "/Users/harryg/Sites/sites">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3: 
   Require all granted
   AllowOverride All
   Satisfy Any
</Directory>
ErrorLog "/Users/harryg/Sites/logs/sites/error.log"
CustomLog "/Users/harryg/Sites/logs/sites/access.log" common
ServerName sites.dev
ServerAlias *.dev
UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
```

This all works great but I donwloaded a copy of cakephp and put it in a directory `~/Sites/sites/cake`. When I visit http://cake.dev I get taken to the cakephp default app page which is expected but there is a warning about url rewriting not being properly configured and stylesheets etc do not load. I followed [the guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html) and tried placing the following in the `.htaccess` for the cake directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But I then get a `500 Internal Server Error`. Error log says:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Suggesting the rewriting rules are conflicting somehow. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. The answer was to simply add the following line to my .htaccess files:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Not sure why it's necessary but it worked!